# Want to add Not like in the sql

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I write Not Like '82' in SQL. I tried but it's not working.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM lot_track_smd.tbl_scrap_wafer WHERE `site` LIKE '$site' AND `pl` NOT LIKE '82' AND `dt_terminate` <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND `status` != '8'ORDER BY `location` ASC";
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you've written? But since `82` doesn't have any wildcard characters in it, `NOT LIKE '82'` is the same as `!= '82'`. Maybe you mean `NOT LIKE '%82%'` to match `82` anywhere in the value?

Comment: What does this have to do with PhpMyAdmin? It has nothing to do with querying MySQL from PHP (except that it's written in PHP).

Comment: yes It's written in php. That's why I added the phpmyadmin

Comment: It has nothing to do with writing your own PHP. PhpMyAdmin is just a tool for managing MySQL databases.

Comment: `LIKE '$site'` looks like a serious SQL injection hole. Use placeholder values for any dynamic data.